# add index on column that contains unique values?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have column that contain unique values and full table scan will take for ever.

from my understanding

If I use  unique index    it will start searching form the beginning of the table and then  stop when it find the value

while non-unique index will search in closest range  of where statement and that what I need

if I have column that contain

```
Maple Louie    
Raphael Gudino    
Nereida Tankersley    
Alina Colletti    
Jeane Lamm    
Shonta Forsman    
Ciara Cardamone
```

if I used non-unique index will it search within the range like

```
where name = Jeane Lamm
```

will the database search for names start with j letter only ?

or it will do full scan ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does database indexing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although indexes can be fully scanned, that is not really how they work for many operations.

When you have an equality, such as `where name = 'Jeane Lamm'`, then the index does a look up.  This is much faster than a scan.

The most common structure for an index is like a binary tree, so the search for a particular value is very, very fast.  That is one reason why indexes can greatly improve the performance of queries.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Based on your experience  for unique column  which one better  to use in mysql   index or unique option ?

Comment: @areviewsapp . . . They do different things.  If you intend for the value to be unique, then use a unique constraint or index.  If you don't want/need uniqueness, then you have to create a separate index.

Comment: Sorry for many question, https://ibb.co/cdtLbT  is there any different in speed between unique and non-unique  index as the picture or both of them are fast  ?    Last question  I noticed  wordpress always  use  non-unique index even for  emails that will not be duplicated that's why I'm asking because the emails always unique but they use index instead of unique  do you have any idea ?

Comment: @areviewsapp . . . I cannot speak for the Wordpress implementation.  There is no performance difference, as far as I know, when using the index for looking up a single name.